# How to view a specific document by key using curl

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

I have a couchdb database. I would like to retrieve the document that has the following key:value :

```
email:example@gmail.com
```

I am new to this.
Should I create a 'design' document. If yes can you help ?

```
curl https://louisromain.cloudant.com/boardline_users/_view/byName?key="example@gmail.com"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes! Create a design document. You want to make a *view* which will index the `email` field of your documents. For example, in a design doc named `_design/users`, if you set `.views.byEmail.map` to this:

```
function(doc) {
  if (doc.email) {
    emit(doc.email, doc);
  }
}
```

Then you can use curl:

```
curl 'https://louisromain.cloudant.com/boardline_users/_design/users/_view/byEmail?key="example@gmail.com"'
```

Note, I've single-quoted the entire URL. That way, the `curl` program will see the double-quotes around the email and it will encode them to send to Cloudant. (Otherwise, Bash would "eat" them and curl would send the wrong value to Cloudant.)

Answer (score -1):

Another option is to make the email address your "primary key", putting email addresses in the _id field. Then you can do something like this:

```
curl https://louisromain.cloudant.com/boardline_users/example@gmail.com
```